# Textbooks for axiomatic approach to algebraic topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Are there textbooks on algebraic topology which first starts with the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms and then derives consequences and applications directly out of the axioms. Only at the end they show there are indeed theories which satisfy the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms.

Comment: You could start at chapter 3 of Vick, and then read chapters 1 and 2. :) For books like this, I'd search for publication dates in the late 1960s to late 1970s. But I have no particular instance in mind.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Foundations of Algebraic Topology](https://archive.org/details/foundationsofalg033540mbp), by none other than Eilenberg and Steenrod.

Answer (score 1):

"A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology" be J. P. May does just that. In chapter 13 May defines homology via the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms. He then proceeds to show that these axioms fully determine your homology theory on CW-complexes, and then, by the "weak equivalence" axiom, to all spaces. The textbook is available on May's website: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf

Answer (score 0):

[Bredon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387979263) does this if you start at chapter IV, section 6. Of course, it's hard to get very far with only the axioms.